# How to save video recording(webcam) and screen recording to directly Mp4 in windows?

Tags: c#, ffmpeg, windows-services, screen-capture, video-recording

I have an applicaiton which running as a windows service which is responsible for Recording the video/audio and screen capture as well.

now I am using DirectX lib and Aforge dll to save recorded file to AVI format which is not supported by HTML 5 so I am then converting the same to mp4 using NVideoConverter dll.

now I am facing high CPU utilization (30% -recording service) FFmpeg (30% conversion task).

So I wanting a solution/method to directly record as an MP4 format to get rid of conversion part as well as CPU utilization.

I couldn't use FFmpeg directly to the record since when user logoff/signout the current recording will get corrupted.

So How can I record as an Mp4 in windows 7 and 10?

also, I came across that win10 default camera application is saving the recording directly as Mp4 file which is playing well in both IE and chrome.

so it means there is a way in windows 10.

If anyone implemented/knows about the same please advise me.

help highly appreciated.

thanks.

Comment: We don't ask for tools or libraries here, please read the help on asking a question